# Use Interface as __constructor() parameter

Tags: php, class, constructor, interface, implementation

I am trying to pass an Interface as a constructor parameter 
into a class that implements it and calls its method .

file: growth.php

```
<?php  
   interface Growth {


        public function growPlants():array;


        }
```

file: forest.php

```
<?php 
class Forest  implements Growth {

        private $growth;

        public function __construct(Growth $growth) {
                       $this->growth = $growth;
                    }

          public   function otherFunction():array {
            $this->growth->growPlants();
        }

    }
```

file: deepforest.php

```
<?php 
class DeepForest implements Growth {

      public   function growPlants():array {
             /* Actions */
       }  
  }
```

file: test.php

```
<?php
 include "deepforest.php";
 include "forest.php";  

$deeforest = new DeepForest();
$forest = new Forest($deeforest);
```

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method deepForest::otherFunction()

Answer (score 3):

According to the error, the variable you're passing to the `Forest` constructor is an array, and not an instance of `Growth`.

Can you post more code, or confirm what class instance you're passing in and whether it itself extends `Growth`?

Comment: i was just trying to create an object of that class but no success. Than i created another class that implements that interface and i passed it as a parameter over the Forest ($newclassobject). Does this mean that in order to create an object that has a constructor based on a interface parameter,  i need to pass an object that is implemented by that interface too ?

Comment: No. A class needs to implement the interface for it to be considered an instance of the interface. Can you edit your question to include the definition of the other class you mentioned?

Comment: Please check it again , i understand that the otherFunction() needs to be under DeepForest() class but it is strange somehow, i dont know.

Comment: Well your original error has been resolved. Where are you calling `otherFunction()` on the `DeepForest` instance to get that error? There's nothing in the code you've posted that will cause that error.

Comment: I think you wants to create a `DeepForest` class which is inherited from `Forest` class. The `Forest` consists of plants which are objects of class `Plant`, and you can grow all the plants in `DeepForest` together, so you create a method called `growPlants()`, which take you to set the Forest class implementing GrowthInterface.  If so, I have the brief code example for you.

Comment: Well the way you are describing it, i see that you are logically right and i don't see another way how to implement this kind of situation. Please let me see the code, thank you.